# After createwindow(...), how to give the window a color?

Tags: c++, window, background-color, createwindow

I have created a window whose handle is handle_parent. Then I created a child window as following:

```
hwnd_child = CreateWindow(child_class_name, _T(""),
WS_CHILDWINDOW, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd_parent, (HMENU)0, ghinst, NULL);
ShowWindow(win->hwndSplitterBar, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(win->hwndSplitterBar);
```

I would like to set the color of child window "child". If I do nothing, the color is grey by default.
How could I set its color? I would like to keep the color as black permanent, do change in anycase.

Comment: How are you painting your child window?

Comment: I don't paint it at all......Is there no direct way to do this, like something setbgcolor(hwnd_child)? I can't find such a direct way, so I came here. I don't know how to paint it, if I need to do this myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a brush of the desired color and then pass it in the `hbrBackground` member of the [`WNDCLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx) struct when calling [`RegisterClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx) to register your window class.

The system will delete this brush automatically when you call `UnregisterClass` so once you have passed this brush to `RegisterClass` you can forget all about it and must not attempt to delete it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

This example may be helpful:

```
//Setting the background color of a window during window class registration
WNDCLASS wc = { 0 } ( or WNDCLASS wc; memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc)); )
...
...
...
wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0x000000ff); // a red window class background
...
...
RegisterClass(&wc);

// Setting the background during WM_ERASEBKGND
LRESULT CALLBACK YourWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM,LPARAM)
{
   switch( umsg )
   {
      case WM_ERASEBKGND:
      {
         RECT rc;
         GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
         SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, 0x000000ff); // red
         ExtTextOut((HDC)wParam, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rc, 0, 0, 0);
         return 1;
      }
      // or in WM_PAINT
      case WM_PAINT:
      {
         PAINTSTRUCT ps;
         RECT rc;
         HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
         GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
         SetBkColor(hdc, 0x000000ff); // red
         ExtTextOut(hdc, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rc, 0, 0, 0);
         EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
         break;
      }
      ...
      ...
      ...
      default:
         return DefWindowProc(...);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CreateSolidBrush()::

WNDCLASS wc = { 0 } ( or WNDCLASS wc; memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc)); )
...
wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0))  or CreateSolidBrush(0x000000ff);  // a red window class background